# Array initialization in C

Tags: c

Can someone please explain me why its not possible to put a `'\0'` character in the given array:

```
char a[]={'r','b'};

a[2]='\0';
```

Shouldn't the above code put a null character at the third slot and hence convert the character array a to a character string.

Comment: You can take `char a[3]={'r','b'};` and you have enough defined memory to put on a[2].

Comment: John Nash asking such basic Question ? naaaahhhh.. /)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are writing past the array boundary: when you initialize an array with two characters, the last valid index is `1`, not `2`.

You should initialize your array with three items, as follows:

```
char a[] = {'r', 'b', '\0'};
```

You could as well use this version:

```
char a[] = "rb";
```

This will give you a *writable* array with a zero-terminated string inside.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Thanks for the prompt reply.

Comment: Since I am new to this, can u help me locate the Accept button. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnNash There's an outline of check mark next to the answer.

Comment: Ok. I just clicked on that check mark and it turned green. I guess, that would mean that the answer has been accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Strings in C are implemented as an array of characters and are terminated with a null '\0'.  Just say  `char* a = "rb";`. (Remember to include string.h)

Answer (score 0):

While TeoUltimus answer is correct, do note that the pointer 'a' in his case will pointing to a string literal. This means you can never modify the string. More specifically, while the code `a[1] = 'c';` will compile, running it will lead to an error. Write `char a[] = "ab"` if you intend the individual elements in the string to be modified.
For details see: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/STR30-C.+Do+not+attempt+to+modify+string+literals

Comment: Thanks, that certainly helped!